# JS: 2 arrays, innerHTML

Tags: javascript, arrays

In my possession, I have 2 arrays. The 1st array is HTML elements. The 2nd array is some strings.

I would like to assign each value of the 2nd array (which is strings) to be the innerHTML of each item in the 1st array (which is HTML elements).

I have a very un-DRY solution here: [This is the Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/old_man_yells_at_cloud/y1px9L57/10/)
(most of my attempts to be clever have been removed).

```js
const second = document.querySelector(".second .blobtext");
const third = document.querySelector(".third .blobtext");
const fourth = document.querySelector(".fourth .blobtext");

const blobs = [second, third, fourth];

const blobAssign = [
  "ur a blob",
  "ur both blobs",
  "no ur a blob",
];

second.innerHTML = blobAssign[0];
third.innerHTML = blobAssign[1];
fourth.innerHTML = blobAssign[2];

//blobs.map( (eachBlob) => {
  // eachBlob.innerHTML = blobAssign;
//})

//blobs.map((eachBlob) => {eachBlob.innerHTML = //blobAssign.forEach((eachAssign) => {
     // ??? 
//  })
//})
```

```css
#arcs {
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
}

.blobtext {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 12vw;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  max-width: 9vw !important;
}

.second {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
  background: red;
  .blobtext {
    font-size: 1vw;
  }
}

.third {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  left: 60%;
  top: 0%;
  transform: translate3d(-60%, 0%, 0);
  background: orange;
  .blobtext {
    font-size: 1vw;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center
  }
}

.fourth {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  top: 0%;
  transform: translate3d(-40%, 0%, 0);
  background: green;
  .blobtext {
    font-size: 0.8vw;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="arcs">
  <div class="big-arc">
    <div class="second">
      <p class="blobtext">[first blob text]</p>
    </div>
    <div class="third">
      <p class="blobtext">[second blob text]</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fourth">
      <p class="blobtext">[third blob text]</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I thought perhaps, I would need to use .map, and doing this: `blobs.map((eachBlob) => {eachBlob.innerHTML = blobAssign;})` - but I'm not sure because that will map the whole 2nd array to eachBlob. But, I can't figure out how get it to be 1 to 1. I was assigning like this: `blobs.map((eachBlob) => {eachBlob.innerHTML = blobAssign.forEach((eachAssign) => {
    eachAssign.somethingHappensHere
  })
})`

Trying to learn this kind of functional programming. Maybe I don't need `.map`, here - maybe `.forEach` - I feel like I just don't know enough to know what I should be using.

Dealing with stuff like this is has been my Achilles heel in web dev for years. This seems simple enough too, but my brain keeps refusing. I feel like I'm either missing something very basic or the way I'm trying to do this is fundamentally wrong.

Any help would be beyond EXCLLNT!

Comment: You should post your code here as a runnable snippet, not elsewhere.

Comment: `blobs.forEach((el, index) => el.innerHtml = blobAssign[index])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your html and js for everyone's reference

```
<div id="arcs">
  <div class="big-arc">
    <div class="second">
      <p class="blobtext">[first blob text]</p>
    </div>
    <div class="third">
      <p class="blobtext">[second blob text]</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fourth">
      <p class="blobtext">[third blob text]</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
const second = document.querySelector(".second .blobtext");
const third = document.querySelector(".third .blobtext");
const fourth = document.querySelector(".fourth .blobtext");

const blobs = [second, third, fourth];

const blobAssign = [
  "ur a blob",
  "ur both blobs",
  "no ur a blob",
];

second.innerHTML = blobAssign[0];
third.innerHTML = blobAssign[1];
fourth.innerHTML = blobAssign[2];
```

What you need to do: `blobs.forEach((el, index) => el.innerHTML = blobAssign[index])`

in a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L5Lhcvp0/1/

Comment: Hi, I don't mean to be rude, but that doesn't seem to do anything. Perhaps there something I don't understand about your answer.

Comment: The question is to replace the individual assignments like: second.innerHTML = blobAssign[0]; to a loop right? where each blob from array 1 has, as it's innerHtml, the matching index from array 2. So the line: blobs.forEach((el, index) => el.innerHtml = blobAssign[index]) does that exactly.

Comment: I understand the logic there, but in the fiddle you posted, the default text is still visible in each blob. My original question might be the problem. Hmmm, I don't know how to ask this question properly, maybe.  I would like default value in the HTML to be overwritten with the values in `blobAssign`

Comment: @user2344204 you are correct, my fault. Used `innerHtml` instead of `innerHTML`, please check now, I updated the answer

Comment: and then I didn't catch that typo because I've been at this for hours...lol...thank you for you help :)

Answer (score 1):

you can go even a step futher from @AhmedMusallam answer and get rid of

```
const second = document.querySelector(".second .blobtext");
const third = document.querySelector(".third .blobtext");
const fourth = document.querySelector(".fourth .blobtext");

const blobs = [second, third, fourth];
```

and include that into the loop:

```js
const blobAssign = [
  "ur a blob",
  "ur both blobs",
  "no ur a blob",
];

[
  ".second .blobtext",
  ".third .blobtext",
  ".fourth .blobtext"
].forEach((selector, index) => {
  let node = document.querySelector(selector);
  if (node) node.innerHTML = blobAssign[index];
})
```

```html
<div id="arcs">
  <div class="big-arc">
    <div class="second">
      <p class="blobtext">[first blob text]</p>
    </div>
    <div class="third">
      <p class="blobtext">[second blob text]</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fourth">
      <p class="blobtext">[third blob text]</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 arrays. The 1st array is HTML elements. The 2nd array is some strings.
I would like to ***assign each value of the 2nd array (which is strings) to be the innerHTML of each item in the 1st array*** (which is HTML elements).

```
const second = document.querySelector(".second .blobtext");
const third = document.querySelector(".third .blobtext");
const fourth = document.querySelector(".fourth .blobtext");

const blobs = [second, third, fourth];

const blobAssign = [
    "ur a blob",
    "ur both blobs",
    "no ur a blob",
];

second.innerHTML = blobAssign[0];
third.innerHTML = blobAssign[1];
fourth.innerHTML = blobAssign[2];


// var copyArrayToHtml = function (aone,atwo){
//     var i,j=0;
//     for( i=0;i < atwo.length ; i++){
//         for( j=0;j < aone.length ; j++){
//             aone[j].innerHTML = atwo[i];
//         }
//     }
// }

//the solution above resolves what you say in the statement.
//this solution always is going to be override with the last value to avoid that you can do the following
var copyArrayToHtml = function (aone,atwo){
    var i,j=0;
    for( i=0;i < aone.length ; i++){
        for( j=0;j < atwo.length ; j++){
            const content = (aone[j].innerHTML) ? aone[j].innerHTML : '';
            aone[j].innerHTML = content + ' ' +atwo[i];
        }
    }
}

copyArrayToHtml(blobs, blobAssign);
```